# Weird error "Unable to copy file ""

Tags: wpf

I am building a WPF application, I got this weird error :

Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\WPF MVVM Application.exe" to "bin\Debug\WPF MVVM Application.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\WPF MVVM Application.exe' because it is being used by another process.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Thanks

_----------------------------

Thanks, it seems like killing the process helps, but it is strange, shouldnt closing the application window kill the process? Thanks

Comment: did you first run it in release mode or something? Make sure all instances of the application are close before you try to compile. If it doesn't work, do a "Clean solution" and try again (Build menu, clean solution).

Comment: Nope, I run it in Debug mode. it seems like the only way to go is to kill the actual process. this is strange, shouldnt closing the application window kill the process?

Comment: Maybe in your application something keeps running in the background when it seems to close. Could be a memory leak or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If killing WPF Application.exe doesn't help, try to stop devenv.exe process to kill Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Hit Ctrl-Alt-Delete and terminate WPF MVVM Application.exe